# Merge two div to have same linear-gradient and shadow

Tags: html, css, merge, shadow

**Hello partners!**

I wanted to see if someone could advise me on how to do the following:

In a webapp that I am making I have a stylized NavBar as seen in the photos (in AdobeXD it is shown as a union of a rectangle with a circle).

[Nav Example AdobeXD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2suW.jpg) | [Complete View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZJRW.jpg)

**How could I make that navbar with HTML / CSS?**

I already have the following but I have the problem of how to merge the div of the rectangle and the div of the circle in order to have the same shadow and the same linear gradient, it is possible to do that?  or would it be better to export that nav as SVG?

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.navContainer{
    width:100vw;
}

.mainNav{
  width:100vw;
  background: linear-gradient(#30355e 0%, #383e6e 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  height: 73px;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

.circleNav{
  width:110px;
  height:110px;
  background: linear-gradient(#30355e 0%, #383e6e 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 57px);
  top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <div class="mainNav">
    </div>
    <div class="circleNav">
    </div>
  </div>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)); /* filter on main container */
}

.mainNav {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#30355e 0%, #383e6e 100%) 
    top/100% 110px; /* 110px = height of circle */
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
}

.circleNav {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: linear-gradient(#30355e 0%, #383e6e 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -75px auto 0; /* same as height of nav */
}
```

```html
<div class="navContainer">
  <div class="mainNav">
  </div>
  <div class="circleNav">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or with a reduced code like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navContainer {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)); /* filter on main container */
  height: 110px;
}

.navContainer::before,
.navContainer::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#30355e, #a3aae4);
}

.navContainer::before {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:70%;
  background-size:100% calc(100%/0.7); 
  background-position:top;
  border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
}

.navContainer::after {
  left:50%;
  aspect-ratio:1/1; /* the support of this is low so you can replace it with width:110px */
  transform:translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="navContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just a question, how it works the "top/100% 110px;" on linear gradient of mainNav?

Comment: @RubenHdezWayne it's `background-position/background-size` .. by defauly the size will be `100% 100%` [width height] but in order to match the gradient of the circle I make its height equal to the height of the circle to have `100% 110px`